# Image covering links

Tags: html, css, image

I am stumped on the following. I just added a logo to a site and for some reason, my nav panel links that are to the right of the logo/image are now not clickable. It appears that the image is somehow over-taking them, but I do not see how. In the console/inspect it doesn't show the image over-taking them?

Does anyone see why this is happening?

```css
.header {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 height: 80px;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: absolute;/*test*/
 width: 100%;
}
.header_wrap {
 margin: 0 4%;
 padding: 2% 0 0 0;
}
.logo {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.logo-img {
 /*height: 75px;
 width: auto;*/
 height: auto;
 width: 25%;
}
.logo a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}
.nav-list > a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list > a > li {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #000;
}
.nav-list > a > li:hover {
 color: #3f3f3f;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
      <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/LogoOpt2.png" class="logo-img" alt="Optimum Designs"></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
          <a href="work"><li>WORK</li></a>
          <a href="approach"><li>APPROACH</li></a>
          <a href="services"><li>SERVICES</li></a>
          <a href="discuss-project"><li>PROJECT</li></a>
          <a href="contact"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
      </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understood whay you have give `position:absolute` to logo but, add `z-index: -1;` to `.logo` will make your link clickable..

```css
.header {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 height: 80px;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: absolute;/*test*/
 width: 100%;
}
.header_wrap {
 margin: 0 4%;
 padding: 2% 0 0 0;
}
.logo {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;
 cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
}
.logo-img {
 /*height: 75px;
 width: auto;*/
 height: auto;
 width: 25%;
}
.logo a {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}
.nav-list > a {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-list > a > li {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #000;
}
.nav-list > a > li:hover {
 color: #3f3f3f;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header_wrap">
   <div class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/LogoOpt2.png" class="logo-img" alt="Optimum Designs"></a></div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
     <a href="work"><li>WORK</li></a>
     <a href="approach"><li>APPROACH</li></a>
     <a href="services"><li>SERVICES</li></a>
     <a href="discuss-project"><li>PROJECT</li></a>
     <a href="contact"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
```

**Edit:**

Other solution is give `display: block;` to `.logo a` will work. **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkavyt8h/3/)**

Comment: What else would you suggest doing than `position: absolute;` for it?

Comment: @Becky No. need of position if you want navbar beside logo. Just use either `display:inline-block` or `display:table/table-cell`

Comment: When I apply `display: inline-block;` to logo it pushes the nav down.

Comment: I added it to `nav-list` too.

Comment: @Becky It because your logo have width in percent. You can try like: https://jsfiddle.net/fkavyt8h/. Else as in answer `z-index`  solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!~

Comment: Because I have the `margin-top: -15px` in my logo, it is effecting the link, so if I am on the top half of my logo, it cannot be clicked on. How can I bring the link up, so it covers the entire logo?

Comment: @Becky Sorry i didn't understood that what you are saying.

Comment: Right here: `.logo {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;` I do this to get the logo to appear higher, so it centers around the nav. However, since I have a link surrounding the image, the image is no longer linked on the top half. If you try to click on the upper half of my logo, you will see it does nothing. I want to bring the link up since I used the negative margin.

Comment: @Becky this is what you want to do. https://jsfiddle.net/fkavyt8h/2/. Give `display: block;` to `.logo a` and remove `z-index:-1` from `.logo`.

Answer (score 2):

The image is not overtaking them but the `<div>` the image is sitting in is. It's full width so you have a transparent div sitting on top of your navbar. Limit the width of your logo container, use a span instead or float it as suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the z-index of the image is below the z-index of the links.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `position: absolute;`. Instead use `display:inline` or `inline-block` and avoid overlapping.

You CSS would look like this:

```
.nav-list {
  display:inline; /* Add this */
    margin: 0;
    /* width:100%;  you can remove this */
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo {
    display:inline; /* add this*/
    margin-top: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* z-index: -1;  no need for z-index */
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35wmzw0m/3/)

Comment: That pushes my nav-list down, though.